# ElasticSearch Date Math Relative to Yesterday

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm looking for a way to get the data for 7 weeks before `yesterday`. This is what I'm using to get data for 7 weeks from `today`.

```
"range" : {
       "gt" : "now-7w/w",
       "lt" : "now"
    }
}
```

I tried something along the lines of:

```
"range" : {
       "gt" : "now-7w/w-1d",
       "lt" : "now"
    }
}
```

but it doesn't seem to output the correct results.

Anyone knows the correct syntax? The Elastic documentation is not very helpful in this case.

Comment: For starters, shouldn't `lt` be `now-1d` ?

Comment: Ah yes you're right! Is the `now-7w/w-1d` syntax correct though?

Comment: Yes, it seems, according to my tests. In terms of dates, given today (2019-06-26), the oldest one you should see is 2019-05-05, because today - 7w = 2019-05-08, rounded to the week = 2019-05-06, and -1d = 2019-05-05

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking at this you probably want the [date math documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#date-math)